# Does UITableViewCell accessoryView has superview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I assigned a `UIView` to a `UITableViewCell's` `accessoryView` then when i try to get the superView of it seems it's nil?

So does `accessoryView` has a `superview`? If no how does it appears?

Answer (score 2):

A view cannot appear on screen unless it has a superview (or is itself a `UIWindow`).

You may be checking the `superview` property before it has been set. The accessory view is added as a subview of the cell by the cell's `layoutSubviews` method. It doesn't happen immediately upon setting the cell's `accessoryView` property.

If you replace an accessory view with another accessory view, the old accessory view will be removed from its superview (the cell) immediately (inside the `setAccessoryView:` method), but the new accessory view won't be added to the cell until the cell's `layoutSubviews` runs.